# How to re-write SQL query to be more efficient?

Tags: sql, optimization, query-optimization

I've got a query that's decently sized on it's own, but there's one section of it that turns it into something ridiculously large (billions of rows returned type thing).

There must be a better way to write it than what I have done.

To simplify the section of the query in question, it takes the client details from one table and tries to find the most recent transaction dates in their savings and spending accounts (not the actual situation, but close enough).

I've joined it with left joins because if someone (for example) doesn't have a savings account, I still want the client details to pop up. But when there's hundreds of thousands of clients with tens of thousands of transactions, it's a little slow to run.

```
select client_id, max(e.transation_date), max(s.transaction_date)
from client_table c
    left join everyday_account e
        on c.client_id = e.client_id
    left join savings_account s
        on c.client_id = s.client_id
group by client_id
```

I'm still new to this so I'm not great at knowing how to optimise things, so is there any thing I should be looking at? Perhaps different joins, or something other than max()?

I've probably missed some key details while trying to simplify it, let me know if so!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and query optimization can be quite vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Have you tried two queries instead?

Comment: Per client you join all their everyday accounts with all their savings accounts. If a client has 100 everyday account rows and 100 savings account rows this becomes 10000 rows which must then get aggregated to get the single row for the client you really want to get. Aggregate before joining as a_horse_with_no_name suggest in their answer, if you need the combination. Or just split the query in two as suggested by Serg.

Comment: An alternative would be to use subqueries in your select clause, but their exist other options as well. You say that this is only part of your query. Maybe it would be a good idea to accept a_horse_with_no_name's answer and make a new request showing the whole query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes aggregating first, then joining to the aggregated result is faster. But this depends on the actual DBMS being used and several other factors.

```
select client_id, e.max_everyday_transaction_date, s.max_savings_transaction_date
from client_table c
  left join (
    select client_id, max(transaction_date) as max_everyday_transaction_date
    from everyday_account 
    group by client_id
  ) e on c.client_id = e.client_id
  left join (
    select client_id, max(transaction_date) as max_savings_transaction_date
    from savings_account
  ) s on c.client_id = s.client_id
```

The indexes suggested by Tim Biegeleisen should help in this case as well.

But as the query has to process all rows from all tables there no good way to speed up this query, other than throwing more hardware at it. If your database supports it, make sure parallel query is enabled (which will distribute the total work over multiple threads in the backend which can substantially improve query performance if the I/O system can keep up)

Comment: As to "there no good way to speed up this query": I disagree. By aggregating before joining as you suggest, you prevent from building a large intermediate result unnecessarily. So, your query should be a *lot faster* than the original.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: e.g. in Oracle the query in my example will result in exactly the same execution plan as the original query. The sweet spot for this kind of transformation for optimizers that don't treat them as identical is, if the results of the individual aggregations can be kept in memory. If they can't, there is not much to gain from this change

Comment: Yep, Oracle's Optimizer, being able to rewrite queries internally, is great. I tried it with rather large tables in Oracle 19c, though, where the combination of client_id and transaction_date (well, different names in my tables of course) made only part of the PK and the cost went down from 35M to 12K with your approach. So it all depends on the real table structure, size, indexes, etc. In my opinion building a cartesian product as the OP does, is almost always very costly.

Comment: In my experience the cost is a bad measurement to judge a query's performance. I have seen queries with a cost of 1T (yes "terra") to run in seconds and queries with a cost of 1M to run for hours. How much faster is the query with the 12k cost vs. the 35m cost?

Comment: That is interesting. I find the costs quite reliable. As to my queries: The 12K cost query took about 9 seconds, the 35M cost query got killed after running several hours.

Answer (score 0):

There are no `WHERE` or `HAVING` clauses, which basically means there is no explicit filtering in your SQL query.  However, we can still try to optimize the joins using appropriate indices.  Consider:

```sql
CREATE INDEX idx1 ON everyday_account (client_id, transation_date);

CREATE INDEX idx2 ON savings_account (client_id, transation_date);
```

These two indices, if chosen for use, should speed up the two left joins in your query.  I also cover the `transaction_date` in both cases, in case that might help.

Side note: You might want to also consider just having a single table containing all customer accounts.  Include a separate column which distinguishes between everyday and savings accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest correlated subqueries:

```
select client_id,
       (select max(e.transation_date)
        from everyday_account e
        where c.client_id = e.client_id
       ),
       (select max(s.transaction_date)
        from savings_account s
        where c.client_id = s.client_id
       )
from client_table c;
```

Along with indexes on `everyday_account(client_id, transaction_date desc)` and `savings_account(client_id, transaction_date desc)`.

The subqueries should basically be index lookups (or very limited index scans), with no additional joining needed.